# CF2021 Getting Started with WebSockets (cfwebsocket)

Tags: websocket, coldfusion

I am just getting started with cfwebsockets and I am having a bit of trouble. What I found from online, is that since this is public-facing application, it is best to use a websocket proxy.

CF2021, Version: 2021.0.03.329779

Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Steps so far:

1. I added the websocket package to my server and enabled web-sockets. Restarted Server.
2. Added this to my application.cfc:

<cfset this.wschannels = [ {name="chat"} ] />

(the application has a this.name= set from a variable as well
3. created a simple page that has this:

```
<cfwebsocket 
name="wSocketObj" 
onMessage="wsOnMessage" 
onOpen="wsOnOpen" 
onClose="wsOnClose" 
onError="wsOnError" 
subscribeTo="chat"
secure="true"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
wsOnMessage =  function(aEvent,aToken) {
  console.log('wsOnMessage',aevent);
  var message = ColdFusion.JSON.encode(atoken); 
  var txt=document.getElementById("myDiv"); 
  txt.innerHTML +=message +"<br>"; 
}

wsOnOpen = function() {
  alert("wsOnOpen Connection is open");
}

wsOnClose = function() {
  alert("wsOnClose Connection Closed");
}

wsOnError = function() {
  alert("wsOnError!");
  console.log(arguments);
}

sendMessage = function() {
  var text = window.prompt("Enter some text","");
  if (text) {
    wSocketObj.publish("chat", text);
  }
}
</script> 
 
<cfdiv id="myDiv"></cfdiv>
<div id="myChatArea"></div>
<input type="text" id="myMessage" /><input id="myButton" type="button" value="Send Message" onClick="sendMessage()" />
```

3. got this in the Chrome Console:

   WebSocket connection to 'wss://myhost.mydomain.com:8555/cfusion/cfusion' failed:
   CFWebSocketWrapper.open @ cfwebsocketCore.js:21
   init @ cfwebsocketChannel.js:49
   _cf_websockets_init_6322652258206397 @ client.cfm:35
   fire @ cfajax.js:1214
   $E.windowLoadHandler @ cfajax.js:1321
   cfwebsocketCore.js:54 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'readyState')
   at WebSocket.wsConnection.onerror (cfwebsocketCore.js:54:29)

thinking it was a firewall issue, I disabled it in Ubuntu

4. It was at this point that it seemed to be that I needed to configure a proxy.
5. I ran /opt/ColdFusion/cfusion/bin/wsproxyconfig.sh from the command line and verified that both the line in apache2.conf was there and the folder "/opt/ColdFusion/config/wsproxy/1/mod_wsproxy.conf" was created. Restarted apache2 and CF2021
6. Same Result
7. Realized I need to change the websocket config in CF Admin,
8. When I select the Use Proxy in CF Admin, the Save Changes button disappears and I cannot save it.

Obviously I am missing something very fundamental here. Any help that anyone can provide would be appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't use any baked in JavaScript functionality in ColdFusion. Currently using `socket.io` in the CF app with a separate NodeJS server to handle websocket calls.

Answer (score 0):

This a know issue, which was reported to Adobe in a couple of bug reports (with one withdrawn as a duplicate). While we await Adobe's resolution, I'll share a workaround I'd offered in those:

> As a workaround, for those who may NEED to enable the "use proxy"
> field (or perhaps to change the other top 3 fields that remain on the
> page), note that if you put the cursor into the "Port" field, you CAN
> hit enter and your browser WILL submit the page (and CF will save the
> change).
>
> You can even leave the page and return to it, to prove that. But even
> after doing so, the submit button will still be "gone", which is not
> right.

If you want to add a vote to or follow the tracker ticket on this, it's at https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4216275.